# Вырезать фрагмент из строки по началу и концу

Tags: регулярные-выражения

как вырезать все подстроки по из началу и концу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу что бы данный код возвращал qqq www eee, но он видит только www

Comment: приложите к сообщению текст из скриншота

Comment: Начало строки, как и конец не есть \B

Comment: можно просто `tac(.*?)att`

Comment: @finally https://regex101.com/r/01omFy/1

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
(tac(.*?)att)
```

Это стандартная задача "Получить содержимое всех тегов"